# Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: relation "users" does not exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, pgadmin

I am getting started with Sequelize.  I am following the documentation they are providing on their website :http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/installation/getting-started.html

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('haha', 'postgres', 'postgres', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'postgres',
  operatorsAliases: false,

  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000
  },

  // SQLite only
  storage: 'path/to/database.sqlite'
});


sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });


  const User = sequelize.define('user', {
    firstName: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    lastName: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
  });

  // force: true will drop the table if it already exists
  User.sync({force: true}).then(() => {
    // Table created
    return User.create({
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Hancock'
    });
  });
```

Up until here, everything works perfectly. And the table "user" is correctly built and populated. (Although I do not understand Sequelize appends an "s" automatically to "user", any explanation.)

[image]

[image]

However when I add the following portion of code:

```
User.findAll().then(users => {
  console.log(users)
})
```

I get this error :

> Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: relation "users" does not
>   exist

So my questions are:

1. Why does Sequelize add an "s" to user. (I know it makes sense but shouldn't the developer decide that)
2. What is causing that error? I followed the documentation but it still didn't work?

Comment: Regarding your first question, according to sequelizejs docs: `By default, sequelize will automatically transform all passed model names (first parameter of define) into plural.` `if you don't want that, set the following: freezeTableName: true,` More can be found here: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html

Answer (score 21):

When you are defining your model you can add configurations, in this case the option that you must add is `freezeTableName` prevents the names from being plural.

```
const User = sequelize.define('user', {
  firstName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  lastName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  }
}, {
    // disable the modification of table names; By default, sequelize will automatically
    // transform all passed model names (first parameter of define) into plural.
    // if you don't want that, set the following
    freezeTableName: true,
  });
```

Answer (score 6):

There is another interesting way you can avoid this. But you need to really focus on this way of implementation.

```
const User = sequelize.define("user", {
    firstname: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    lastname: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
  });
```

you intentionally put `user` here and use `users` in other places of coding(Assume sequelize will automatically transform all passed model names (first parameter of define) into plural) . This way of coding will simplify your code.

Answer (score 5):

This problem occurs because creating a table is an asynchronous function. The problem is, the findAll() function can get executed while the table has not been created.
to solve this, you can use:

```js
(async ()=>{
    await User.sync({force: true});
    // Table created
    const users=await User.findAll();
    console.log(users);

})();
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem, in my case, was that the table `users` was not created. You can create the table manually with `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` (SQL) or add the `tableName = "users"` in the options object:

```js
export const User = db.define('user',
    {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
        },
        name: {
            type: new DataTypes.STRING(128),
            allowNull: false,
        },
        email: {
            type: new DataTypes.STRING(128),
            allowNull: true,
        },
        password: {
            type: new DataTypes.STRING(128),
            allowNull: true,
        },
    },
    {
        freezeTableName: true,
        tableName: "users"
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Run that code twice.

Before running the second time, comment out the following code,

```
// force: true will drop the table if it already exists
User.sync({force: true}).then(() => {
  // Table created
  return User.create({
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Hancock'
  });
});
```

Comment: I know the tutorial doesn't say that. I was going thru the tutorial right now and figured it out after looking at your question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe answer is not entirely connected with you question but I want to describe my experience with this error

> Error: relation "users" does not exist.

It appears Sequelize make migrations based on migrations file names and it alphabetical order. My problem was my files naming was not sorted in order to create proper connections.
If you face with this problem make sure yours migration files are fired in proper (in alphabetically) order.

The proper order is to first migrate table without connections (eg. table_A) and then tables with connections to table_A.

As I said this may not be answer for your particular order but I want to share my experiences because I didn't find this information on the internet when I was looking for this error.

Answer (score 1):

Simply append `tableName: "Users"` to your model configuration.

The easiest way I found to solve, is to explicitly set the `tableName` on the model. As others have mentioned, sequelize defaults to the plural form of a model as the table name. For instance User, becomes Users.

When you query, sequelize looks after a table with the same name as your model `User`. By defining the `tableName` in the model, sequelize should search the correct table. Append `tableName: "Users"` to your model configuration i.e:

```
 User.init(
        {
            email: DataTypes.STRING,
            password: DataTypes.STRING,
            role: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        },
        {
            sequelize,
            modelName: 'User',
            tableName: 'Users',
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want Sequelize to use a singular word ('info') for a model and that same singular word for the table ('info'), you can name the model 'info' and also add `tablename: 'info'` to the definition of your model.

This is a way to control Sequelize's default behavior of pluralizing model names, or not, on a table-by-table basis.

```
info.js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const info = sequelize.define('info', {
    firstname: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    phone: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {
      tableName: 'info'
  });
  return info;
};
```